# Can a ternary be used with i18n in an AngularJS template?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

Normal ternary use in Angular template:

```
{{ isOn ? 'meow' : 'woof' }}
```

Simple question, will this work with i18n?

```
{{ isOn ? 'meow' : 'woof' | i18n }}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Simple response...did you try?

Comment: Not yet. If I get a chance, I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

The string data type is not affected, so the result will be the same as normal. The i18n spec converts the following types:

- number object
- date/time data
- empty date/time object

**References**

- [i18N Converter Spec](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/i18n/spec/converterSpec.js)